# how to solve 't.rangeslider is not a function' here rangeslider is custom function

Tags: javascript, angular

I'am using function that was assign to variable.But it throw error...
code is given below.

```
$(".sliderRange").each(function() {
var t = $(this);
t.rangeslider({
    polyfill: !1,
    onSlide: function(e, a) {
        var n = 0;
        1 == t.data("index") ? ($("#loanAmount_1").val(a), n = a, a = "Rs. " + NumberFormat(a)) : n = t.val();
        var l = $('input.sliderText[data-index="' + t.data("index") + '"]');
        l.val(a), validate(l, n)
    },
    onSlideEnd: function(t, e) { PLEMI() }
})
```

I have got the below error.

> PLcustom.min.js:92 Uncaught TypeError: t.rangeslider is not a function

Any one can help in this code??

Answer (score 0):

Though sharing the function definition of`rangeslider` and where it is defined would be very helpful but anyway if rangeslider is custom function, just change `t.rangeslider` to `rangeslider`